# El boton submit no me recarga la pagina PHP

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo un error, ya que cuando oprimo el botón "submit" de mi formulario, no me redirecciona a la página, lo que estoy haciendo es primero traer el id de la tarea que el usuario quiere editar y despues con ese id, traer el título y la descripcion para imprimirlo en un formulario.

Hasta ahí está bien, el problema que tengo es que en el formulario al presionar el boton tipo submit no me recarga la pagina para que este pueda ejecutar el codigo que actualiza la pagina.

Envio fotos de el modelo, la vista y el controlador

Modelo:

```
class editar_model extends Conexion {
private $bd;

public function __construct() {
    $this->bd = Conexion::conexion();
}

public function get_tareas() {
    $id_t = $_GET['id_t'];

    if (!$stmt = $this->bd->prepare("SELECT title, description FROM task WHERE id = ?")) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $this->bd->errno . ")" . $this->bd->error);
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_t)) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error);
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" .$stmt->error);
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_result($titulo_t, $descripcion_t)) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $this->bd->errno . ")" . $this->bd->error);
    }

    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();


    return array($titulo_t, $descripcion_t, $id_t);
}

public function set_tareas() {
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $id_a = $_GET['id_a'];

    if (!$stmt = $this->bd->prepare("UPDATE task SET title = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $this->bd->errno . ")" . $this->bd->error);
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $titulo, $descripcion, $id_a)) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error);
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error);
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

}

Controlador:

```
require_once('models/tareas/editar_model.php');
$editar = new editar_model();
if (isset($_GET['id_t'])) {
    $tarea = $editar->get_tareas();
}

if (isset($_POST['btn_editar'])) {
    $tarea_e = $editar->set_tareas();
}

require_once('views/tareas/editar_view.php');
```

Vista:

```
<div>
<form action="index.php?id_a=<?= $tarea[3] ?>" method="post">
    <label for="titulo">Titulo:</label>
    <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" value="<?= $tarea[0] ?>">

    <label for="descripcion">Descripcion:</label>
    <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" rows="2">
        <?= $tarea[1] ?>
    </textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="btn_editar" value="Editar">
</form>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Viendo el código fuente en el navegador: `<form action="index.php?id_a=<?= $tarea[3] ?>" method="post">`, vos podes visualizar que `$tarea[3]` imprime algo realmente?

Comment: Ya lo probe y definitivamente tuve un error de novato, muchas gracias por la ayuda porfa ponla como respuesta ya que al imprimir el array el dato que queria sacar estaba en el puesto 2 no en el 3 muchas gracias